# Getting error using generic T on xs.Serialize(fs, T);

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following code that uses generic type:

```
public static bool SaveConfigurationData<T>(string filePath)
        {
            bool returnVal = false;

            try
            {
                // Create and XmlSerializer to serialize the data to a file
                XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                string textSerialized = string.Empty;
                
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    xs.Serialize(fs, T);
                }
                
                returnVal = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                returnVal = false;
            }


            return returnVal;
        }
```

But Im getting the following error on the line:  `xs.Serialize(fs, T);`

[image]

> Any clue?

Comment: Take a closer look to 'xs.Serialize(fs, T);'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have done is said that your method works with a generic type of `T`, which will be whatever type the caller provides, but you have not actually provided a variable of type `T`, or a parameter of type `T`. Normally, it you wanted to serialize something of type `T` in your method, you would have something like the following.

```
public static bool SaveConfigurationData<T>(T data, string filePath)
{
    ...
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        xs.Serialize(fs, data); // data is of type T
    }
    ...
}
```